# remove item from my export list highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Hi everyone I try to remove o hidden the last item from my export list of my graphic using Highcharts

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
        contextButton: {
            menuItems: {[{
                text: 'Export to PNG (large)',
                hidde: true ,
                separator: false
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

I try `remove` `hidden`  but nothing work, any idea how to do that.

Thank in advances!

Comment: Just don't put it in the `menuItems` array: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've spelt 'hidde' wrong in your code.